# MacOSでvscodeの初期設定に関する問題です

Tags: vscode

[image: ランニングしたら次のコードが出ています]
MacOSでvscodeにプログラムを稼働したら、cinが入っているのに入力する場所すらなかった理由を教えてください

Comment: ターミナルでコマンドを実行しているのではなく、何かしら拡張機能をお使いのように見えます。何を使ってらっしゃいますか？

Comment: 長時間返信してなくて申し訳ありません。今回の問題について、今run codeを使っていますが、毎回の結果が出るまでに随分遅くて、しばらく経ってから実行しないと前の結果しか見えないような状態です。

Comment: [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) をお使いですか？